# Get WordPress Custom Field Content Outside Loop

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I have tried following the WordPress Codex and several different variations from examples both here and on WordPress. Several different functions. From all I've read, I should have had this working multiple ways, but I can't get this simple code to access the content of a custom field for a custom post type, outside the loop.

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$snr1l = get_post_meta($post->ID, "show_nav_red_1_link", true);
$snr1t = get_post_meta($post->ID, "show_nav_red_1_title", true);
echo '<li><div class="image"><a href="' . $snr1l . '">' . $snr1t . '</a></div><div style="clear:both"></div></li>';
?>
<ul>
```

I used 'More Types' and 'More Fields' for their parts, I have verified that I'm getting the post ID and I have verifed the field slugs/indexes.

Am I missing something? (I was up 'till 5am trying to get this working so it could be brain fog)

I would greatly appreciate any advice.

Comment: What does this code output?

Comment: It outputs content of a custom text field.

Comment: Yes, but what does it actually look like?  Post the HTML that this code generates.